# extract data between dates from MYSQL into pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, date

```
**When i am running below query**

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import datetime
db_connection_str = 'mysql+pymysql://root:*****@localhost/northwind'
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM employees where BirthDate between '1948-12-08' and '1960-05-29'', con=db_connection)
df

**I am receiving below Error**

  File "", line 7
    df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM employees where BirthDate between '1948-12-8' and '1960-5-29'', con=db_connection)
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes to enclose the sql statement since you use single quotes inside the statement for the dates:

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM employees where BirthDate between '1948-12-08' and '1960-05-29'", con=db_connection)
```